page.evaluate: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation
I'm getting the error "page.evaluate: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation".  This is happening using Light-Playwright for performance testing.
here's the actual code:


import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test';
import playwright from 'playwright';
import { audit } from '../utils/audit';

test.describe('Top 20 sites', () => {

  test(`Ligthouse User Journey performance test`, async () => {
    test.slow();
    const browser = await playwright['chromium'].launch({
      args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Find Hotels' }).click();
    // const context = await browser.newContext();
    // Create a new page in a pristine context.
    const results = await audit(page, 'userFlow')
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    // expect(results.lhr.categories.performance.score, `${'https://www.marriott.com/default.mi'} fell below the minimum threshold`).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(.30);
  });
});



It fails on the playAudit because the page has changed as a result of the click action.  How do I grab the new page after the navigation completes.  I've tried doing a new page context to no avail.
The audit method is Lighthouse's audit:


export const audit = async (page: Page, reportDir: string) => 
    playAudit({
        page: page,
        config: lighthouseDesktopConfig,
        thresholds: thresholds,
        port: 9222,
        reports: {
          formats: {
            html: true, //defaults to false
          },
          name: `ligthouse-${new Date().toISOString()}`, //defaults to `lighthouse-${new Date().getTime()}`
          directory: `${process.cwd()}/lighthouse/${reportDir}`, //defaults to `${process.cwd()}/lighthouse`
        },
      });



